How to create read-only calendars in Outlook.com
This is a question how to best architect a solution.
I run an application that generates calendar events. Now several of our users want these events in their preferred calendar app. So we built a calendar sync service (.ics URL) that works great, most of the time.
Both Google and Outlook.com allow users to subscribe to these URLs but they have a horrible refresh rate, going from hours to days. I guess this is a conscious choice on their end, as this basically forces us to integrate with their APIs to create a good user experience.
In this situation we are looking at Outlook.com, and we are trying to sync our users events into their calendar. This should happen in a read only way ideally. What would be the best way to go about this in the Microsoft cloud solution space? After a few hours of navigating their docs, I'm absolutely overwhelmed. It's unclear what APIs to call, what type of app I need to set up, let alone what is actually the best solution for our specific use case.
Any help or guidance here would be appreciated.

Are you okay for the solution using Microsoft Graph Explorer/Api?

Any update on the issue?

To set the calendar as read only, check the below:
I created a calendar:


canEdit is set to true for the user who created the calendar and if the user can write to the calendar, false otherwise.  This property is also true for a user who has been shared a calendar and granted write access.

Now you can set the user as reader to the calendar like below:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/CalendarID/calendarPermissions

{
    "emailAddress": {
        "name": "ruk",
        "address": "ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    "isInsideOrganization": true,
    "isRemovable": true,
    "role": "read"
}


If the above do not suit your requirement the refer this blog by Bruce Johnsonto to set calendar to be read-only for members for group members.
References:
outlook - Create readonly calendar event with Microsoft Graph API - Stack Overflow by Domenic
Create calendarPermission - Microsoft Graph v1.0 
